# delete first 2 white spaces from start of line in gvim

Tags: vim

I am reading a file which has 2 unwanted spaces in each line.

```
  import uvm_pkg::*;
  `include "uvm_pkg.svh"
```

And it continues till last line
How to delete first 2 white spaces in each line in gvim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter `:%s/^  //`, which `s`ubstituttes 2 leading whitespaces (`^`  ) with nothing (the nothing between the second and third `/`) on every line (`%`).

Answer (score 1):

1. position cursor at line 1, column 1 (press `gg0`)
2. enter visual block mode (Ctrl+v)
3. select first two columns of all lines by moving the cursor to the bottom and one to the right (`Gl`)
4. delete selection (`x`)

Answer (score 1):

```
 :%s/^  //
```

substitutes the two first leading spaces on every line of the buffer with nothing, effectively deleting them.

Note that, in this case, you don't even need the replacement part because it is implied: `:%s/^`  .

See `:help :s` and `:help :range` for the `%`.